# Classifying a number as big, medium, or small using prolog?

Tags: prolog, classification

Currently trying to solve a problem in my class for Prolog using a predicate classify(+N, ?Classification):
small numbers are below 50, medium numbers are between 50 and 100 (inclusive), and big numbers are above 100. For example, classify(24, X) should succeed with X = small.

I have the simple classifications down, but I'm unsure how to set up the actual predicate.

```
small(X) :- X < 50.
medium(X) :- X >= 50, X =< 100.
big(X) :- X > 100.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to connect the "number" to the representative of its "class", which in this case is one of the atoms `small`, `medium`, `big`. This fits what the exercise demands:

```
% classify(+N, ?Classification)

classify(N, small)   :- ...guard...test N for smallness...
classify(N, medium)  :- ...guard...test N for mediumness...
classify(N, big)     :- ...guard...test N for bigness...
```

The "guard" can check that `classify/2` was called with "`N` a number", not something else and possibly an as-yet unbound variable. Depending on circumstances that can be left out, otherwise one can make use of a predicate like `must_be/2`:

So we write:

```
classify(N, small)   :- must_be(number,N), N < 50.
classify(N, medium)  :- must_be(number,N), N >= 50, N =< 100.
classify(N, big)     :- must_be(number,N), N > 100.
```

We also know that only one of the three cases can succeed for an `N`, so we can tell Prolog that, if success has been achieved, there is no need to try an alternative, by using `!` at the end of the first two clauses (you can add it to third clause too, but it doesn't do anything there, it being the last clause):

```
classify(N, small)   :- must_be(number,N), N < 50, !.
classify(N, medium)  :- must_be(number,N), N >= 50, N =< 100, !.
classify(N, big)     :- must_be(number,N), N > 100.
```

And so:

```
?- classify(100,How).
How = medium.

?- classify(100,big).
false.

?- classify(100,medium).
true.

?- classify(N,medium).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```